# replace each word with specific word javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace every word in a string with a certain word.

```
var str = "hello how are you can you please help me?";
```

and wish to arrive at the following

```
answer = "bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye";
```

Currently, I have

```
var answer = str.replace(/./g, 'bye');
```

which changes each letter to `bye`. How do I change it so that it just targets each word, and not each letter?

Comment: Each "word" or a chunk of non-whitespace characters?

Comment: I am looking to replace each word

Comment: then how are you replacing `?` ?

Comment: But `me?` is not a word, it is a word+punctuation symbol. So, you want to replace `me?` as `bye bye`, right?

Comment: apologies, if that is what you meant, i mean replace on chunk of whitespace

Comment: Then, no need using regex, see Ali's solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why would you choose to use a loop over regex? what is the advantage?

Comment: Choose what is easier for you. I do not insist on anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but you are the master of regex! ;-)

Comment: if there is anything that can be done without regex(and is not complicated), you should avoid regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
str.replace(/[^\s]+/g, "bye");
```

or

```
str.replace(/\S+/g, "bye");
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY7iT8/2)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var str = "hello how are you can you please help me?";
document.writeln("<pre>" + str.replace(/\S+/g, "bye") + "</br>" + "</pre>");
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks..i always forget small things

Answer (score 0):

Small solution (**without regex**):

```
var 
  str = "hello how are you can you please help me?";

str.split(' ').map(function(a) {

  if (a === '') return;

  return 'bye';

}).join(' '); // "bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye"
```